# Pass Variables To PHP Script Without Submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the code below to capture an 'onlick' event in the deletion of images. Once selected my 'delete.php'script is called and the physical images are deleted from the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        Galleria.ready(function() {
            this.$('thumblink').click();

        $(".galleria-image").append( 
        "<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); 
        $(".btn-delete").live("click", function(){
        var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img"); 

        // send the AJAX request
        $.ajax({
        url : 'delete.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : { image : img.attr('src') },
        success : function(){
        alert('Deleting image... ');
        img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
        }
        });
```

The problem I'm having is that because the 'click' event is not posting the form, I'm unable to capture the 'userid' and 'locationid' variables to pass them through to the receiving script i.e. 'delete.php.

I know this to be the problem because if I use:

```
<?php session_start(); 

$_SESSION['userid']=$_POST['userid'];
$_SESSION['locationid']=$_POST['locationid'];
```

The rest of my 'delete.php' script doesn't work. However if I use:

```
<?php session_start(); 


$_SESSION['userid']=2;
$_SESSION['locationid']=1;
```

The rest of my script works fine.

I'm relatively new to PHP, and I'm unsure whether there is a solution to this.

But I just wondered whether someone may be able to have a look at this please, and offer some guidance on how I may go about overcoming this problem?

Many thanks and regards

Comment: is your userid and locationid available in UI? will you be able to post your form?

Comment: You can add your needed info in the img tag as attrbiute mean
<img src="" data-uid="userid here" data-loc="location here" />

Then in jquery you will make variables as
var uid = $(this).attr("data-uid");
var loc = $(this).attr("data-loc");
Then do your ajax with this paraetrs

Comment: Hi both, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. You'll see by my final answer that I've found the solution. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass the values in the data object of your ajax call:

```
var sessionUserid = <?= $_SESSION['userid']; ?>;
var sessionLocationid = <?= $_SESSION['locationid']; ?>;
data : { image : img.attr('src'), userid: sessionUserid, locationid: sessionLocationid },
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. Unfortunately, although I receive no error message, upon inclusion of the additional information, the gallery function stops working properly. By this I mean that the Thumbnail view' is no longer presented to the user. Kind regards

Comment: Do you have an error in the browser javascript console (Like the Chrome or Safari Developer Tools or FireBug in FireFox)?

Comment: Hi @davidehell, it's ok, please don't go to anymore trouble. I've found the solution and I've posted this is my answwer. Once again many thanks for your time and trouble. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

After some further experimenting, I found the solution to my problem.

I changed this line `data : { image : img.attr('src'),` to 
`data : { image : img.attr('src'),  userid: "VALUE", locationid: "VALUE"},` it works fine. Kind regards

Comment: that's basically the answer I gave you. I just included the example of setting the data with PHP inline scripts as an idea, but the solution was to add the userid and locationid to your AJAX data.